# How create Set with unique Objects using data from Object to compare?

Tags: java, set, unique, treeset

I have TreeSet of "Var"
Var is my own class:
http://pastebin.com/pXC4q2YB

And I need to "string" be unique for that TreeSet of Var
so any Var from set can't have this same "string"/".getKey()"

---

I override compareTo method, but when I adding values to that set...

This still adding Var's with this same key...

---

I add some debug... and compareTo don't run for some combinations.

For start I have 8 variables, and I keep adding next, but every time some of Var.replace are different, so after second adding I have 14 elements... after some more... 30, and that end, after get 30 Var in set it's stop adding next.

---

PS: I using that code to adding:
http://pastebin.com/N372QUck

"variables" is that Set of Var

I using this code very often so that can't be slow, and 8 variables is only for testing, that can by ~50 or more if someone want.

Comment: It's probably easier to use a `Map` to use the keys as keys and store the values as something like `new Var(replace, types)`, isn't it? With this, you won't have problems with your duplicate keys and the `compareTo` method, because a map can only hold unique keys. Think about!

Comment: @bobbel Ach... stupid me... I trying some Map<String, Map<String, Type[]>> and other weird and over-complicated things... But I even don't think about that easy Map...
Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

The key thing in TreeSet is that natural ordering is not just used for Object comparison but also to traverse along the Tree.

You have really made a big flaw with your compareTo method used to implement natural ordering.Let me paste the code and then point out its flaws:-

```
               @Override
                public int compareTo(Var var) {
                        if (var == null)
                                return 1;
                        return var.getKey().equals(this.getKey()) ? 0 : 1;
                }
```

Violations in our Comparable's compareTo method:-

1)The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y. (This implies that x.compareTo(y) must throw an exception iff y.compareTo(x) throws an exception.)

Your above code will allow multiple null values as it returns 1 instead of throwing NPE

2)TreeSet is self balancing tree.What that means is that what you consider objects as equals may not be used by treeSet for comparing as it keeps on adding objects.Treeset will traverse the tree in a specific order as defined by Comparable or Comparator and keep traversing between the nodes according to the value returned by compareTo (-1,0,1).Hence,It is highly possible that your "equal" objects are not even encountered for comparison while adding an element.Note,TreeSet is not a ordinary sequential traversal like a List or an Array but a tree traversal.

To solve the issues,you need to be sure that your compareTo(Var var) method follows the equals contract of Object

The better code would be:-

```
           @Override
            public int compareTo(Var var) {
                    if (var == null)
                            throw new NullPointerException("Object is null");
                    return this.getKey().compareTo(var.getKey()) ;
            }
```

This should solve all your problems

Comment: hyym, I actually use bobbel idea, but I also try this, and:
I still see 8 elements in Set so is good... BUT this not "updating" value from set. new "Var" must replace old.

But still thanks, I remember that "rules" maybe I will need that in other code :>

Answer (score 0):

[compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) is used to to evaluate greater/lesser/equal.

Equality in terms of a Set is determined by overriding the [Object#equals(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method.
You should also implement the hashCode() method, whenever you implement equals().

Comment: I using also equals but... When I added debug I don't saw any debug-messages from equals method